# Why content of inline-block display div goes on next line and how to stop it?

Tags: css

I try to use a display:inline-block with an image and some text, but the text goes on the next line, after the image. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/skwnb5vq/2/. Could you please help me to fix this?

```
<div class="user">
    <div class="user-img">
        <img src="..."></img>           
    </div>
    <div class="user-name">     
        <span>Lorem </span>
    </div>
</div>

div.user{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
div.user-img{
    width: 30%;
}
div.user img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
div.user-name {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 1em; 
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(0,121,191);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because block level elements occupy the full width of the page even if you make its width smaller. If you float the image to the left, you'll see it's removed from the normal flow and behave as you want. It is the ["normal flow"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#normal-flow) that keeps your text from coming up to where you want it.

Comment: True, thank you. But if I make div.user-name {
 display: inline-block; } it still does not work. Why? Of course I will try the float

Comment: @Alex Because user-img is block level and occupying its complete width. Change that to inline-block.

Comment: It still is not working. Can you please help me with that? Please see http://jsfiddle.net/skwnb5vq/4/.

Comment: @Alex Just float:left div.user-img